# Cannot access SSM from AWS ECS task using .NET Core console app

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-ssm

I have written a .NET Core 3.0 console application that accesses SSM for some encrypted credentials to run a job. When I run it locally, it works fine and I can access the parameters from my account's SSM. However, when I deploy this via docker and ECS Fargate and run it as a task, it seems like it can't access the parameters. I get the following error:
*Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.*
This is coupled with a *ParameterNotFound* exception.

As I understand it,`AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient` is trying to grab the default app config and use the aws credentials from there to access other aws resources. This works fine when I run it locally since I have the AWS CLI configured and my credentials are accessible. When this runs through ECS, I guess that it can't find this config so it then tries to look for the EC2 Meta config, which may not exist in ecs?

I have attached the SSM Full access policy to the task definition's role and even the AdministratorFullAccess role and still doesn't seem to fix the exception. Am I missing something?

```
        public static async Task<Login> GetCredentialsAsync(string parameterName)
        {
            var request = new GetParameterRequest()
            {
                Name = $"/credentials/{parameterName}",
                WithDecryption = true
            };

            using (var client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = await client.GetParameterAsync(request);
                    var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Login>(response.Parameter.Value);
                    return responseObject;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            throw new ParameterNotFoundException($"Could not find credentials for {parameterName}");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I needed to set a Task Role for the instance in the Task Definition. I had only set an Execution Role.

Comment: You can accept your own answer